# how to find deviation in Java of two lines

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, java-8

I would like to make a very simple app which on app initialization is drawn a straight static line and than it gives the user opportunity to draw another line (user will try to follow the first line) and at the end calculate what was the deviation or the difference between these two lines.

Something that comes in my mind is to first store all the points(cordinates) X1,Y1 of line A and same for line B in separate arrays and iterate over both arrays and calculate the difference using the Pythagorean formula from https://www.mathplanet.com/education/algebra-2/conic-sections/distance-between-two-points-and-the-midpoint

My current implementation is this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.*;

public class DrawLine extends JPanel implements ActionListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {    

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  LinePoint[] lineA = new LinePoint[300];
  LinePoint[] lineB = new LinePoint[300];

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

     for(int i = 0; i < lineA.length; i++) {
         lineA[i] =  new LinePoint();
     }

     int initialLocationPoint = 10;
     for(int i = 0; i<lineA.length; i++) {
         lineA[i].x = initialLocationPoint;
         lineA[i].y = 100;
         g.drawOval((int)lineA[i].x, (int)lineA[i].y, 1, 1);
         initialLocationPoint +=1; 
     }

  }

  public double calculateDifference() {
       double deviation = 0.0;
       double deviationPerPoint = 0.0;
       for (int i = 0; i < lineA.length; i++) {
          deviationPerPoint = Math.sqrt( Math.pow(2, (lineB[i].x - lineA[i].x))  + Math.pow(2,(lineB[i].y - lineA[i].y)));
      }
      deviation = deviation +deviationPerPoint;
      return deviation;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw Line");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setBackground(Color.white);
    frame.setSize(400, 400);

    DrawLine panel = new DrawLine();

    frame.add(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse clicked.");

        LinePoint lp = new LinePoint();
        lp.x = arg0.getX();
        lp.y = arg0.getY();
        lineB[0] = lp; // 0 should replace with some variable so it does not override first element

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse entered.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse pressed.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse drawged.");
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("mouse moved.");
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("action performed.");
    }
}

class LinePoint
{
    double x;
    double y;
}
```

Well I do have problem also with mouseListener not capturing the mouse click or drag or anything.

Anyone could help me complete this task?

Comment: Why is this tagged C# ? Which one is it? Java or C# - pick one.

Comment: its Java. you should tag what its related with only.

Comment: @Fildor it does not really matter the language as it is pure OOP. but yeah i can remove c#

Comment: Well, it does not matter for _you_ but it is not very useful if a question that seemingly is all about Java gets answers in C#. See, SO wants to provide high quality answers to specific questions that not only help the OP but are useful for people having the same problem. Transferring a Java answer to a Java question to a different language may be possible but someone looking for Java answer will probably freak out over finding answers in C#. That's like googling for pictures of German cars and being presented Hondas.

Comment: @Fildor you right, srry i didnt pay too much attention on this, but I guess I should have!

Comment: Nothing to be sorry about. Just wanted to explain why it is more useful for everyone to stick to one language. Didn't mean to rant.

Comment: You are never registering any listener. It’s not enough to implement the listener, you also have to invoke the associated `add…Listener` method on the component you wish to receive events from. Though, it is a bad coding style to let the component itself implement a listener interface. And don’t reinvent the wheel. Instead of creating a `LinePoint` class, you can use [`Point2D.Double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/awt/geom/Point2D.Double.html).